# How to make a MacBook look like an iPhone to a gateway

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, network

I'm aware it sounds fishy, but I swear it's not. If someone can reword the title, please do so. I'm in a dire situation where I bought a costly time limited WiFi access on my iPhone.

I stupidly presumed that the Hotspot the iPhone can produce, would allow my MacBook go online too. Of course that was wrong, as the Hotspot uses mobile data.

So I thought I can make my MacBook to look like an iPhone to the network as I received no password and I think no cookies are involved, as I can go online in every browser or app. I've tried to set the MAC address of the values of the iPhone (the WiFi, not the Bluetooth ones) and change the MacBook's name to iPhone (in the file sharing prefs, not sure if I should look somewhere else).

Is there something more I could do?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot modify MAC addresses _at all_.  They are permanently "burned into" network hardware at the time of manufacture.   Are you sure there isn't a way to de-authorize your iPhone from that plan somehow so you can connect your MacBook to it?

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it, I used this command to change my MAC address:

```
sudo ifconfig en0 ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

But it should have been en1 for WiFi :)

Sorry I forgot my login